# Does the theory of equivalence relations have quantifier elimination?

Tags: logic, model-theory, equivalence-relations, quantifier-elimination

I am aware that the theory of equivalence relations *with infinitely many classes, all of which infinite*, has quantifier elimination, as can be seen from the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546838/quantifier-elimination-for-theory-of-equivalence-relations). However, does the theory which consists only of the axioms stating that $E$ is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric, have quantifier elimination (in a first-order logic with equality)? I'm inclined to say no, but I don't really know how even to begin the proof either way. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = \{a,b,c\}$ and let $E$ be the equivalence relation on $X$ with classes $\{a\}$ and $\{b,c\}$. Then $a$ and $b$ satisfy the same quantifier-free formulas in one free variable (the induced substructures on $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are isomorphic). But $b$ satisfies the formula $\exists x\, [xEy\wedge x\neq y]$, while $a$ does not. So this formula is not equivalent to any quantifier-free formula.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought; what threw me off was that Chang & Keisler ask in an exercise to give "a decision procedure for this theory by the method of elimination of quantifiers" (exercise 1.5.9 of the 3rd edition). I wonder what they could have in mind?

Comment: Doesn't every element of every model satisfy $\exists x \; xEy $?  By reflexivity, that is.

Comment: @hardmath what if we include in the conjunct $x \not = y$?

Comment: @Nagase: I thought the Question was about a language (and theory) that only has the predicate $E$, not equality as well as $E$.

Comment: @hardmath - well, equality is generally considered as a logical constant, which is why I didn't bother to mention it explicitly. Sorry if that was confusing. I edited the question to mention it explicitly.

Comment: @hardmath Oh, oops, of course I mean $\exists x\, (xEy) \land (x \neq y)$. As Nagese says, first-order logic contains $=$ by default. If you want an example without equality, use $\exists x\, \lnot (xEy)$, which is true of any singleton in a structure with more than one class, but not true of any singleton in a structure with just one class.