# Exercise 3.4.1 Markers model theory

Tags: logic, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

I am working through some exercises from Marker's *Model Theory* in self-study and I am stuck at Exercise 3.4.1 as I do not know how to formally prove that a theory has quantifier elimination. I am aware of the definitions and possible checks but I cannot come up with a formal proof or an intuitive way to check if they do not have quantifier elimination.

Can someone help me by guiding me through the exercise? I would appreciate the effort as I am really trying to learn. Thank you very much.

Let $L = \{E\}$ where $E$ is a binary relation symbol. For each of the following theories either prove that they have quantifier elimination or give an example showing that they do not have quantifier elimination and a natural $L'\supset L$ in which they do have quantifier elimination.

a) E has infinitely many equivalence classes all of size $2$.

b) $E$ has infinitely many equivalence classes classes all of which are infinite.

c) $E$ has infinitely many equivalence classes of size $2$, infinitely many classes of size
$3$, and every class has size $2$ or $3$.

d) $E$ has exactly one equivalence class of size $n$ for each $n < \omega$.

Comment: @William Elliot: I agree that the [relations] tag isn't appropriate here. But why did you remove [logic]?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. Please use MathJax (similar to LaTeX) formatting on this site. I've edited to add this formatting to your post. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you already know that, to prove quantifier elimination for a theory, it suffices to eliminate the quantifier from formulas of the simple form $\exists x\,\phi(x,\vec y)$ where $\phi$ is a conjunction of atomic formulas and negations of atomic formulas? Since your $L$ has only one relation symbol (along with equality), there aren't very many atomic formulas. Try to eliminate the quantifier from $\exists x\,\phi$ for the various possible $\phi$'s. If it works, you win. If it doesn't work, that will suggest what to add to $L$ to produce a suitable $L'$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman ok thank you, I will consider that next time!

Comment: @AndreasBlass, yes I do know that, however the proofs I have looked at construct some kind of back-and-forth argument (for example for dense linear orders) but I am struggling to come up with a formal proof construction like this myself.

Comment: I think you might be conflating two different proofs of the completeness of the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints. One proof goes via $\aleph_0$-categoricity and Vaught's test for completeness; the categoricity is established by a back-and-forth argument. The other proof goes via quantifier-elimination; I don't see any back-and-forth in this second proof. And the second is what you should imitate here, since you're explicitly asked to prove quantifier-elimination.

Comment: For parts (c) and (d) you can take some inspiration from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774848/does-the-theory-of-equivalence-relations-have-quantifier-elimination).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For the negative results, note that the set of elements whose classes have $n$ elements for a fixed finite $n$ is definable, but often not quantifier-free definable. On the other hand, after you make these sets quantifier-free definable, you can just prove q.e. directly, [like in this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3694256/30222).